Copying a color range\profile form one image to another in Photoshop elements?
In photoshop elements 11 or above, is it possible to copy the color range\profile from one image file to another?
If so, how do I go about this?
For example, if a series of images were take under the same circumstances\using the same camera setting, and were saved as PNG or JPG files, rather than DNG, and one of them is edited to remove a color cast, or to change the brightness\contrast, can the new color profile be created from that image and applied to the other images.
This is specifically for instances where only the edited image is available and no information from any previous version has been preserved, including camera or metadata.

AFAIK PS store the changes you do in DNG file w/o user interaction. So you have it already. And in Camera RAW you can copy or sync the changes from edited image to others.

I'm looking for a mechanism to do this where there is no preserved data, only the edited file.

I do not get it. You have the changes in DNG file.

@ Romeo Ninov I'm looking for a way to do it when you don't have the DNG file, for example, if somebody else took the picture, or if the original DNG file was lost or deleted.

Check if the resulting JPEG have in meta information the changes done on the original. This can be checked via extracting EXIF info.

@Romeo Ninov, I'm looking for a solution based on the image alone.

This information is stored INSIDE the image. Just check!

@Romeo Ninov, I understand what you're saying, but I'm only looking for answers where this information is extracted from the image itself. Not from the RAW files or Meta data. I'm not invalidating what you are saying, but looking for an answer in a very specific and narrow range.

This already is clear definition. But how do you define what is edited/changed and what is from the original photo?

@Romeo Ninov, It doesn't matter what is an edit and what is original. I'm looking for a technique to copy the color profile, from one image to another. For example, if I have a two pictures of the same flower, and I use the remove color cast feature on one picture, I want to be able change the other picture to match in a situation where there is no RAW file and no meta data. Just the image data. Similarly to how Lightroom would create a color curve adjustment layer based on one image, and then apply it to another (Which Photoshop Elements can't do).

Photoshop Elements 2024 (and full versions of Photoshop) has a color match tool. In Elements it is in the Effects options.
You can import your reference photo and Photoshop will attempt to apply the same color grading to the image being edited. If the images are close enough it may do a good job.
https://youtu.be/TCKQmPomDP4?si=3_W11uzMkr4ryiR6

Not from that image alone. With the proper utilities you can create a "Color Lookup Table" from the edited image and the original image and apply it to other images to obtain results similar to your editing (if the images are similar enough).
See here for some more explanations on the subject.

So, not Photoshop Elements version 11 or above?

Not with anything if there is no original image to compare with to figure out what was done.

so, no equivalent of a color curve?

It is not  a "curve", which is a one to one mapping (or three independent mappings, one per channel). A CLUT is a mapping of RGB triplets to other RGB triplets (so for instance, what happens to the blue component may depend on the red component of the same pixels). And curves or CLUT, you can't guess what has been done from just the result.

@ xenoid The color curve feature is often used to map colors form one image to another, (https://medialoot.com/blog/how-to-easily-copy-a-color-grade-from-any-image-in-photoshop/) Photoshop elements lacks this feature.
